Why are there bubbles slowly appearing in my kitchen wall?
The wall is behind the range in my kitchen. We had it painted three years ago and now it has several bubbles in it. What could be causing them — would it be damp? Or something else?
It's an exterior wall. There's no mold or other obvious signs of damp, but I did notice a larger patch a bit further down that looks like the paint may be coming loose.




I see no evidence of moisture issues in these pictures. Are you pushing the range against the back wall causing nail pops?

Looks like water incursion to me but not enough info to tell.  The middle pic is a curiosity since it looks like a puncture from outside in.
If it is water, you should track down the source before mold takes hold.  Very hard to mitigate once it's taken hold not to mention health risks.  You can get a moisture meter at the big box store for small money and if it measure wet, engage a leak detection company.

the wall was contaminated and not clean when painted, and/or not primed well enough for good paint adhesion.
to think it's always caused by water or moisture, is just not correct.
i don't understand how you first say it's the wall behind your kitchen range then say it's an exterior wall.

I read "exterior wall" as meaning this wall is on the edge of the building and has no other room on the other side.  It is exposed to the outside world on the other side of this wall, so it likely has insulation inside and a weatherproof cladding outside.
